# Router module not loading my settings module

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

So, here is my app-routing.module.ts code is where i have written some routes:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BackopsModule } from './modules/backops/backops.module';
import { DetailsModule } from './modules/details/details.module';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './components/admin/admin.component';
import { SettingsModule } from './modules/settings/settings.module';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'distributor-admin-login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent },
  { path: ':userid', loadChildren: () => BackopsModule },
  { path: ':userid/merchants/:merchantid', loadChildren: () => DetailsModule },
  { path: ':userid/settings', loadChildren: () => SettingsModule },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here's my settings.module.ts code which i have imported in app-routing.module:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CreateMerchantComponent } from 'src/app/components/settings/create-merchant/create-merchant.component';
import { EditGrantsComponent } from 'src/app/components/settings/edit-grants/edit-grants.component';
import { IntegrationComponent } from 'src/app/components/settings/integration/integration.component';
import { MisReportComponent } from 'src/app/components/settings/mis-report/mis-report.component';
import { ResetPasswordComponent } from 'src/app/components/settings/reset-password/reset-password.component';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SettingsComponent } from 'src/app/components/settings/settings.component';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { SmtpConfigComponent } from 'src/app/components/settings/smtp-config/smtp-config.component';
import { AddAmcComponent } from 'src/app/components/settings/add-amc/add-amc.component';
import { SmtpFormComponent } from 'src/app/components/settings/smtp-config/smtp-form/smtp-form.component';
import { EmailSettingComponent } from 'src/app/components/settings/email-setting/email-setting.component';
import { EmailSettingsFormComponent } from 'src/app/components/settings/email-setting/email-settings-form/email-settings-form.component';
import { CreateBackopsUserComponent } from 'src/app/components/settings/create-backops-user/create-backops-user.component';
import { OrderBy } from 'src/app/components/backops/pipes/order-by/order-by.component';
import { DistributorSettingsComponent } from 'src/app/components/settings/distributor-settings/distributor-settings.component';
import { ViewDistributorFlowsComponent } from 'src/app/components/settings/distributor-settings/view-distributor-flows/view-distributor-flows.component';
import { CreateDistributorFlowsComponent } from 'src/app/components/settings/distributor-settings/create-distributor-flows/create-distributor-flows.component';
import { ViewFlowsComponent } from 'src/app/components/settings/distributor-settings/view-flows/view-flows.component';
import { FilterPipe } from 'src/app/components/backops/pipes/filter-pipe/filter-pipe.component';
import { TrackByPipe } from 'src/app/components/backops/pipes/track-by/track-by.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: ':userid/settings', component: SettingsComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CreateMerchantComponent,
    EditGrantsComponent,
    IntegrationComponent,
    MisReportComponent,
    ResetPasswordComponent,
    SettingsComponent,
    SmtpConfigComponent,
    AddAmcComponent,
    SmtpFormComponent,
    EmailSettingComponent,
    EmailSettingsFormComponent,
    CreateBackopsUserComponent,
    OrderBy,
    DistributorSettingsComponent,
    ViewDistributorFlowsComponent,
    CreateDistributorFlowsComponent,
    ViewFlowsComponent,
    FilterPipe,
    TrackByPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(appRoutes),
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    SettingsComponent
  ],
  providers: [Location]
})
export class SettingsModule {}
```

All my backops module, details module are loading up. But my settings.component.ts is not rendering when i am on route : `http://localhost:4200/5aa00d6533a8b84362602ba0/settings`. Can anyone help me in any direction

I tried adding ngOnInit in settings component, but it doesn't log anything.

Answer (score 0):

> setting module is render on ':userid/settings' ,
> so settings route should be,
> const appRoutes: Routes = [  { path: '', component: SettingsComponent }],
> if you want to render SettingsComponent on ":userId/settings",

Comment: i agree but that gives me this error :  NavigationError(id: 1, url: '/5aa00d6533a8b84362602ba0/settings', error: TypeError: Illegal constructor)

Comment: I think you should change approach. your nested outlet should be like this `parent routerModule **{ path: 'settings', loadChildren: () => SettingsModule } ** child routerModule **{ path: ':userid', component: SettingsComponent }**  ` which will be more easy and manageable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).